# Search table for keyword

Tags: php, mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have a website that basicly consists on a video search engine, I have the follow code that will query mysql for the given input criteria:

```
$search=htmlspecialchars($_GET['load']); 
$say=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM madvideo WHERE MATCH (baslik) AGAINST ('*$search*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
```

Then I have the follow code that will display the results:

```
     $katala=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM madvideo WHERE MATCH (baslik) AGAINST ('*$search*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) order by id asc limit $s,$perpage");
            $i=0;
                    while ($sea=mysql_fetch_array($katala))  { 
            $i++;

$idd=$sea['id']; $seoo=$sea['seo']; $baslikk=$sea['baslik']; $resimm=$sea['resim']; $suree=$sea['sure'];
 $izlenmee=$sea['izlenme']; $tarihh=$sea['tarih']; $katt=$sea['kat'];
```

Let me try to explain what's the problem with this.
Lets say you search on my website for "I like to eat strawberry"

And lets suppose I have on mysql table an entry with the very same name "I like to eat strawberry"

With my current code I will get the follow example results:

"I like to drive my car"
"my car is super fast"
"they eat to much"
and so on, and the relevant result might appear but not at first like I would like to be.

How can I make it display the results in a more relevant way, like the google for example?

Comment: Create a formula that defines "relevancy"? A simple implementation would count the number of matched keywords.

Comment: @lc - To be fair, it's not that simple.  For example `'I do not like to eat strawberry'` will have exactly the same number of word matches as `'I like to eat strawberry'`.  One could consider mis-matches, order, similies, context, etc.  And thus the question could be `Does anyone know of a 'relevancy' algorithm that has already been implemented in php or mysql?`

Comment: @Dems Agreed it's much more complicated than that, I was simply suggesting a starting point which would be better than nothing and hopefully prompt further research.

Comment: Thanks for replying guys, ive been playing around with this code, and i noticed whats the real behaviour of this code, so heres what i discovered: if i search with my current algorithm for "boy likes strawberry" it will be displayed the results for "boy" then after the results for "likes" and for last the results for the keyword "strawberry". im starting to learn php so i dont have the perfect sense what could be easly done or not with php, so please be patience im trying really hard to enter the php world.

Answer (score 2):

Break the search term into words so you can build the order by condition dynamically using `like` expressions. Since the result of a logic expression in mysql is 1 or 0 you can add those expressions.

```
SELECT * 
FROM madvideo 
WHERE MATCH (baslik) AGAINST ('*$search*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
order by 
    (baslik like '%$word1%') 
    + (baslik like '%word2%')
    + (baslik like '%word3%')
    desc
limit $s,$perpage
```

Comment: Thanks Clodoaldo, i implemented your code, but i got the follow error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /usr/home/user/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/search.php on line 96 wich have the follow on line 96:  while ($sea=mysql_fetch_array($katala))  {  . do i have to do something to avoid the displayed error? thanks again

Comment: $katala=mysql_query("SELECT * 
FROM madvideo 
WHERE MATCH (baslik) AGAINST ('*$search*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
order by 
    baslik like '%$word1%' 
    + baslik like '%word2%'
    + baslik like '%word3%'
    desc
limit $s,$perpage");
           $i=0;
     while ($sea=mysql_fetch_array($katala))  { 
            $i++;
            
$idd=$sea['id']; $seoo=$sea['seo']; $baslikk=$sea['baslik']; $resimm=$sea['resim']; $suree=$sea['sure'];
 $izlenmee=$sea['izlenme']; $tarihh=$sea['tarih']; $katt=$sea['kat'];
  ?> thats what i have now

Comment: @DaniQueiroga Sorry it is necessary to surround the expressions with parenthesis. I edited the answer. Also you are missing the `$` from `$word2` and `$word3`.

Comment: Thanks for correct code, i apllyed your changes and the error gone, but i get exactly the same results, i think the best solution is look over other free scripts that reproduce what i want and take it from there, trying to do this from scratch for me is like looking for something in the dark. Thanks anyways for all the help and efforts